# Kinect V2 COMException when construct VisualGestureBuilderDatabase

Tags: kinect, comexception

I created a windows8.1 app with Kinect, but when I tried to construct the `VisualGestureBuilderDatabase class`, however my program throws **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**.

I totally don't know why. I use *VS2015* and the program stops at the *App.g.i.cs*:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine.
I forgot to set the gdb file's Copy to Output Directory property to Copy always and Build Action property to Content.